# Android poor graphics performance

Tags: android, performance, surfaceflinger

I run Android 9.0 on RCAR-H3 MCU. Sometimes the GUI (all applications) very slow and I saw in the logcat the log like below:

```
W SurfaceFlinger: Timed out waiting for hw vsync; faking it
```

Did the problem come from graphic driver ?

Comment: This looks more like something is taking up too much time on the UI thread.  SurfaceFlinger has to do with scrolling, so most likely someone is calculating too much in an onScroll or RecyclerView adapter's bind function

Answer (score -2):

Are loading image from URL or assets?

If you'r using url than in android Glide Library is best to load images in android. Here I have add some sample code below.

````
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(model.getImage())
                .apply(RequestOptions.noTransformation())
                .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL )
                .priority(Priority.IMMEDIATE)
                .into(holder.imgcategory)
                .waitForLayout();```
````

Comment: It is not the problem of specific app. The whole system was slow